# I am doing the full outer join and getting error

Tags: mysql

here is an [image of current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQDH7.png)

```
select em_first_name, em_department, em_designation 
from employee_master 
FULL OUTER JOIN
si_users 
ON 
employee_master.em_first_name = si_users.si_name;
```

and I am referring this w3school example

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

employee_master is my first table and si_users is my second table.

Comment: You would there is no full join in mysql, try googling mysql full outer join.

Comment: @P.Salmon . . . I would add that `full join` is rarely needed for most queries.

Comment: Thank you, I got but how to select all records using join

Comment: Why the post get deleted is anyone

Comment: guys can you explain

Comment: No pictures, thanks. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Karthik You can use `outer join` in mysql instead of `full outer join`

Comment: The query is right. There are no values in em_first_name that match a value in si_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the image you provided I see a `si_users.si_name` = **'Suraj'**

But in that same image I do **NOT** see `employee_master.em_first_name` of the same name, they have values like **'KA' 'kkkk'** etc. There is no first name that equals an si_name at all. So a query which asks for `employee_master.em_first_name` = `si_users.si_name` isn't going to work very well.

On top of that, the "full outer join" isn't allowed in MySQL (although that join type is allowed in some other databases).

So there are multiple problems, most of which we cant help solve because you have access to the tables and data - but we don't. If you **supply some sample data from each table** (but **not** an image) then, perhaps, we could suggest something that would work.